# Stop flipping-back of an image after mousehover with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 images in sifrelimatematik.com under Matematik-Geometri section. When you hover on images they flip 360 degrees with these codes;

```
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 55%;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 110px;
    height: 90px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 1.2s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding-bottom: 98px;
    position: relative;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:  2;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: ;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

but I want images to stop flipping after mouse-hover. When I scroll somewhere else, i dont want it to flip back.

like this example here; lewendewoordmoot.co.za/ (under Afdelings section)

how can i do this? Thanks for help!

Comment: paste your html also

Answer (score 0):

I think the `animation` property may help.

You can define a new animation called rotation for example.

```
@keyframes rotation{
    to{transform:rotateY(360deg)}
}
```

And you can use `animation` instead of `transition`.

```
.flipper{
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation: rotation 1.2s ease infinite;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper{
     animation-play-state: running;
}
```

And if you want it to play alternatively, you can add:

```
.flipper{
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Have a try!